# SQLite compare 2 columns and modifiying same row?

Tags: sqlite, if-statement, row

I have sqlite db with addressbook table with phone column and address column.
I will like to search for any addres ending with abc and then see if phone lengh this same row is = number and then insert of the begining of number another number:

Example Code to give an IDEA:

```
SELECT * FROM addressbook
WHERE address like '%abc' AND phone.lengh=5
THEN replace phone by 43.phone(i mean here the old value phone use to have.)
```

In this case i want to modify this row like this: and nothing to do with the second example because have more characters that the one i'm looking for.

phone
4322174             annan abc

Please help... kind regards...

Answer (score 0):

That shuld do the trick

```
UPDATE addressbook SET phone = '43'+phone WHERE address like '%abc' AND length(phone)=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE addressbook SET phone = '43' + phone WHERE address LIKE '%abc' AND length(phone) = 5;
```